# Zookeeper (Curator framework) : explicitly giving up the leaderLatch

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system, apache-curator

***Background***

I have a web-socket consumer running on 1 of my backend servers. To keep this system HA,     i want to keep 2 more standby machines in the setup. Expectation is ->  1 of the standby VM should takeover the role of my primary webs-socket consumer, in either of the below scenarios.

> 1. Primary web-socket consumer going down
> 2. Primary web-socket consumer voluntarily giving up the leadership due to some in-built health-checks failing on it.

***Question***

Was wondering if there is an out of the box zookeeper recipe for powering this setup. Initially i tried using 'LeaderLatch' as the prefererred recipe. But a Leader Latche doesn't allows the construct to voluntarily give up the leadership. (Scenario number **2** mentioned above).

What would be the best suited Curator/Zk recipe for the above scenario. Any example/guidance appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Based on this: https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/leader-latch.html you can call `latch.close()` to give up the latch explicitly. Is there anything wrong with using that?

Comment: Thanks Petr. Yes, latch.close() works one time. But 'close' being a terminal state, i cannot toggle it any further. Am looking for something which supports toggling multiple times (contrary to 1 time movement supported by latch).

Comment: Hm, so unless you can just recreate the latch, I'm afraid you'll need to write something yourself. It's not terribly complicated: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection, but obviously you'll need to test the living soul out of it.